# How to make this display an extra field

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the following code to do what I need it to do.

```
c.forEach(function(item,index) {
    dd.append(app.getOptionHtml(
        item.get('idRoom'),
        item.get('roomNumber'),
        page.roomCheck.get('idRoom') == item.get('idRoom')
    ));
});
```

If I change `roomNumber` to `id_address` it displays the value for id_address.

What I am trying to do is get it to show both values. I need `roomNumber` and then `id_address`.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can use `item.get('roomNumber') + item.get('id_address')` instead of `item.get('roomNumber')` e.g.

```
c.forEach(function(item,index) {
    dd.append(app.getOptionHtml(
        item.get('idRoom'),
        item.get('roomNumber') + item.get('id_address'),
        page.roomCheck.get('idRoom') == item.get('idRoom')
    ));
});
```

or better

```
c.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var roomId = item.get('idRoom');
    var roomAddress = item.get('roomNumber') + item.get('id_address');
    dd.append(app.getOptionHtml(
        roomId,
        roomAddress,
        page.roomCheck.get('idRoom') == roomId
    ));
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I have been scratching my head all morning. I did try using + but i was getting undefined. I just used the 4th line of your code and it worked :)

Thanks again,

Clint